# no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "pgadmin", database "postgres", SSL off on OSX

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

```
local  all  postgres    trust
host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

I would think either the second or the third would match these criteria.

I've restarted my service on brew with brew service restart postgres@9.6

Am I missing some setting here?

Answer (score 4):

First, the meanings of the fields  are:

```
# local       DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host        DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host[no]ssl DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
```

The attempt is:

host = “[local]” (meaning through a [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket))

user = “pgadmin”

database = “postgres”

SSL = off

Now your lines:

```
local  all  postgres    trust
```

does not match because the user pgadmin is not postgres

```
host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

does not match because `host` only matches TCP/IP connections and [local] is not a TCP/IP connection.

```
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

does not match for the same reason than the previous line.

If you want to "trust" everyone locally through the Unix domain socket, you may change the first line to:

```
local  all  all    trust
```